# XMLHttpRequest, send and security restrictions

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, try-catch

I thought I could catch an error in send like this

```
try {
    xhr.send();
} catch(e) {
    // fix-me: With the
    // bookmarklet on a https page
    // you can't even send a HEAD
    // request due to security
    // restrictions. Check for
    // this case here.
    console.log("xhr.send, e=", e, method, window.location.href, url)
    debugger;
}
console.log("I am here now");
```

However I never get to that console.log statement in the catch block after xhr.send.

In the console I instead get a message like this.

```
Mixed Content: The page at 'about:blank' was loaded over HTTPS,
but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'http://m.org/'.
This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

I am here now.
```

Is it supposed to work this way? (I am using Google Chrome.)

Is there any way to find out that there was an error? (Except looking in the console. ;-) )

**UPDATE**
@giuscri added the very good question if I did consider that this is async. I actually missed that it could be, but it is not. A bit surprisingly. ;-)

Please see the [this example](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/848981/it/tests/xhrerr/xhrerr.html). It contains this code:

```
var url = "http://nowhere.org/";

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    console.log("onreadystatechance, readyState=", xhr.readyState);
};
xhr.onprogress = function(event) {
    console.log("onprogress, readyState=", xhr.readyState);
    console.log("onprogress, event=", event);
};
xhr.onerror = function(event) {
    console.log("onerror, readyState=", xhr.readyState);
    console.log("onerror, event=", event);
};

var method = "HEAD";
xhr.open(method, url, true);
try {
    xhr.send();
} catch(e) {
    console.log("xhr.send, e=", e, method, window.location.href, url);
}
console.log("After send");
```

When you run this page from `https://` (as in the link above) the onerror function is not run. If you run the same example from `file://` then onerror is run.

Comment: Are you sure that you understand the asynchronous programming pattern? `xhr.addEventListener("error", function () { console.log("The request has failed."); })`. See [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/#event-xhr-error) and [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)

Comment: Good question, @giuscri. I updated my question. It does not work as you expect.

Comment: Does `onload` fire with a `xhr.status` of `0`? That's what usually happens on cross-origin requests.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, @Bergi, but it `onload` does not fire. The only event that fire is `readystatechange` (with xhr.readyState == 1).

Answer (score 2):

Connecting from HTTPS to HTTP URIs drops the security given by the underlying encryption. Web browsers blocks such requests until explicitly allowed by the user in order to prevent data leakage over plaintext connections. Further, there is also a change in origin (scheme, domain, port).

I allowed Mixed Content for the page you linked and I got the error about the different origin in console. Looks like the code works.

By the way, support for synchronous requests using `XMLHttpRequest` is deprecated, because it blocks user interaction until the request completes.

Comment: Thanks @Kagomeko, good to know (though I think I never used `XMLHttpRequest` synchronously ;-) ).